# magento product list

Tags: magento

I need to load a different layout page (two_column instead one_column) when url is something like mysite.com/category.html?flag=1
So I've done an override to getParam('flag').
How can I replace layout programatically (without set it on xml such a custom design)?

```
if ($flag) {
 // set custom_layout.phtml
} else {
 // set 1column.phtml
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the layout and modify the template used by the `root` block.  Something along the lines of:

```
$template = "page/3columns.phtml";
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate($template);
$this->renderLayout();
```

This needs to be done a controller action.